# How I can access to my application after a war deployments in wildfly 8

Tags: java, wildfly-8

I used to work on tomcat I try to deploy my app on wildfly 8 ,there a message said that deployment succes but I dont know how I can access to my app I used to use my app using for example : http://localhost:8080/Gnrqst/Api/enqueteurs on tomcat but now it's not working I ask is there another port to use on wildfly ? Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're including a `jboss-web.xml` given the name of your deployment the context name would be `Gnrqst-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. If you'd like the `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` to be removed you need to either rename the file before you deploy it or use a `jboss-web.xml` to define the context name.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web version="10.0"
       xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_10_0.xsd">
    <context-root>/Gnrqst</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Answer (score 3):

Wildfly has the same default port (8080) for http so it should work.

Look at the `standalone.xml` file to see the current configuration (it is usually the very last of that file).

```
 <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
```

There are two relevant settings. The port-offset= that applies to all values and the binding for "http". Make sure it is same as the snippet.

If you didnt change the settings, most likely the port is used by another application(sure tomcat is not running anymore?) or was used while starting (restart should work)

If wildfly actually works and servs content under that port you might want to try another address `http://localhost:8080/Gnrqst-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Api/enqueteurs`