# Why do I get 404 error on RESTEasy (wildfly) after deploy?

Tags: java, rest, maven, wildfly, resteasy

I have created simple 3 files in Java, and used mvn clean package wildfly:deploy command to run it. It all deployed successfully (at least thats what is written in console). However, when I go to

http://localhost:8080/lab-rest-api/library/book

I get 404 error. My project is located in module lab-rest-api (its just a part of a project, other modules are for web consume - ejb, ear etc)

I did web service and simple web consuming and it worked out fine. However, REST API is not working.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My extend Application:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class RESTMain extends Application {
    public RESTMain() {
        System.out.println("whatever");
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(ServicesInterface.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

And my service:

```
@Path("/library")
@Consumes({"application/json"})
@Produces({"application/json"})
public class ServicesInterface {

    Book booky = new Book();

    @GET
    @Path("/book/{title}")
    public Book getBook(@PathParam("title") String title){
        return booky;
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/book/{title}")
    public Book addBook(@PathParam("title") String title, @QueryParam("author") String author){
        return booky;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/book/{title}")
    public Book updateBook(@PathParam("title") String title, String author){
        return booky;
    }


    @DELETE
    @Path("/book/{title}")
    public Book removeBook(@PathParam("title") String title){
        return booky;
    }

}
```

"Book" is a simple class with 2 Strings (author and title) and getters and setters for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so,

Steps to fix this :

1) Packaging a war

Add `<packaging>war</packaging>` to your pom file.
Also add

```
<plugin> 
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> 
  <version>2.4</version> 
  <configuration> 
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> 
    </configuration> 
</plugin>
```

2) Upgrade wildfly maven plugin

```
<version.wildfly.maven.plugin>2.0.1.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>
```

3) Remove duplicate dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

4) Remove this extra stuff from **wildfly-maven-plugin** configuration

```
<inherited>true</inherited>
<configuration>
    <skip>true</skip>
</configuration>
```

5) Run your `mvn clean package wildfly:deploy`

6) Browse to http://localhost:8080/**lab-rest-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT**/library/book/asd

BONUS : Accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859083/how-i-can-access-to-my-application-after-a-war-deployments-in-wildfly-8) shows how to remove *-1.0-SNAPSHOT* from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You seems didn't implement the `Get` for `\book`. You only implemented `\book\{title}`

for your current implementation, try `\book\{meaningful title in your database}`

Comment: Project name is "labok" and when I add it to the path like this:
http://localhost:8080/labok/lab-rest-api/library/book
it still shows 404

Comment: Still doesn't work. Even when I delete the parameter and just want to return the book without the title (deleted the \{title}) it still shows up 404

Comment: Try localhost:8080/labok/lab-rest-api/library/book/1

Comment: Nothing's changed, still 404

Comment: Do you have the project on github/gitlab ? It seems you have a problem with your embedded web server.

Comment: No, but I can add it. Just give me a minute.

Comment: erasing the "/" from paths didn't change anything.
https://github.com/Lauralicja/web-project
Heres the project

Comment: Are you sure you really have some books for query?